# Reset results and TextUtil

Tags: java, android

So, I got a feedback from reviewer and fixed most of my problems but there are two problems that I can’t find solution (I will use bold font to highlight them) the first problem comes after I click result button more than one time because the previous result is added. I know that I should add all the methods checkQuestionOne to checkQuestion6 in the button method but this is not possible so far because the method needs (View or view value) which is not working and I don’t know why so I decided not to include the four Radio buttons methods in it. Second when the checkQuestionFive is blank or there is no value the app crashes I was told to use if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(gettingQuestionFive.getText())), then I add Toast message into the if statement but it still crashes. Any help will be appreciated!!

Thank you!

Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int health = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void checkQuestionOne(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.question_one_yes:
                if (checked)
                    health += 1;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void checkQuestionTwo(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.question_two_yes:
                if (checked)
                    health ++;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void checkQuestionThree(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.question_three_no:
                if (checked)
                    health ++;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void checkQuestionFour(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.question_four_no:
                if (checked)
                    health ++;
                break;
        }
    }

    **public void checkQuestionFive**() {
        EditText gettingQuestionFive = findViewById(R.id.sleep_hours);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(gettingQuestionFive.getText())){
            Toast displayError = Toast.makeText(this, "You missed question 5, plase don't leave it blank", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            displayError.show();
        }
        int answerQuestionFive = Integer.parseInt(gettingQuestionFive.getText().toString());

        if (answerQuestionFive >= 7) {
            health ++;
        }
    }

    public void checkQuestionSix() {
        CheckBox checkBoxOneA = findViewById(R.id.fruits_check_box);
        CheckBox checkBoxOneB = findViewById(R.id.chips_check_box);
        CheckBox checkBoxOneC = findViewById(R.id.candy_check_box);
        CheckBox checkBoxOneD = findViewById(R.id.all_three_check_box);

        if (checkBoxOneA.isChecked() && !checkBoxOneB.isChecked() && !checkBoxOneC.isChecked() && !checkBoxOneD.isChecked()) {
            health++;
        }
    }

    **public void overView(View view)**{
        checkQuestionFive();
        checkQuestionSix();
        Toast displayToast = Toast.makeText(this, health + " is your score. If is 4 or above, you have a healthy life", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        displayToast.show();
        health = 0;
    }
}

XML code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.martinevtimov.quizapp2.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/group1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1. Do you eat healty?"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_one_yes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:onClick="checkQuestionOne" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_one_no"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:onClick="checkQuestionOne" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/group2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2. Do you work out?"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_two_yes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:onClick="checkQuestionTwo" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_two_no"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:onClick="checkQuestionTwo" />


        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/group3" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3. Do you drink?"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_three_yes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:onClick="checkQuestionThree" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_three_no"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:onClick="checkQuestionThree" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/group4" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4. Do you smoke?"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_four_yes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:onClick="checkQuestionFour" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/question_four_no"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"
                android:onClick="checkQuestionFour" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5. How many hours do you sleep?"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sleep_hours"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Type here"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6. What is a healthy snack?"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fruits"
            android:id="@+id/fruits_check_box" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chips"
            android:id="@+id/chips_check_box" />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Candy"
            android:id="@+id/candy_check_box" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="All three"
            android:id="@+id/all_three_check_box" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="overView"
            android:text="Check my health"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question explains the problem assuming everyone here knows what your app is about and what it does and what is expected out of it. Can you explain what these questions are, what is the user doing, what is the expected output and what is the real output. And then mention the issue that you are facing in trying to get the expected output? Share screenshots of the app screen so we can understand the use case better. Also add any exception logs as text here instead of as an image and highlight the line that the exception is being thrown in.

Comment: Sorry about that posting my answer as an Answer Your Question.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Logcat and the message error I have. The purpose of this app is to make a quiz app with 3 different inputs (EditText, Radio Buttons, and CheckBoxes). When the EditText is left blank, a crash appears. It seems there is some problem with the onClick attribute in your code but I can figure it out. The second problem comes from clicking the check button more than one time than more points are added to the previous points, I tried to add all the question methods into one and then set the global health variable to 0 but is not really working.  Also, take a look of the two pictures below my code.

[Screen Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3j7m.png)
[Screen Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwAa3.png)